# mysqli query returning true on null

Tags: php, mysqli

I read that a successful `sqli->query` will result in an object while a failed one would result in a false. With that in mind, I wrote this code:

```
//first test if account is already awaiting activation
$query="SELECT * FROM activate WHERE email = '$email'";
//if it is awaitign activation....
if ( $result=$mysqli->query($query) )
{
    PrintError("Email already registered. Please check your spam folder for activation email",6);
    return;
}

//if it is not awaiting activation, test if username is alreay taken
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . user_table. " WHERE username = '$user'";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))
{
    PrintError("Username already registered. $result->num_rows Please select another",3);
    return;
}
```

Now, considering that both tables are completely empty as this is the first user being created, I would have assumed that both queries would return false but instead, the first table is queried, it returns `null` and the error is not printed... but the second query, that returns true. It actually returns an object but with 0 entries. You will notice I added a `$result->num_rows` in the resulting error message and that gives me a value of `0`.

So why does the first query to an empty table return a false or a null while the second query to an empty table returns an empty (but existing) object and this fulfills the conditional?

Oh, and before you ask, `user_table` is defined higher up in the script.

Comment: _successful_ means that it didn't encounter an error, such as a syntax error in the SQL. It doesn't mean that it found any rows. For that, you should use `$result->num_rows`.

Comment: Interesting... so you are saying that , since I am getting a null for $result, it means that the query most likely encountered a problem... As simple as the query is, perhaps there is a mistake in the query? Hmmm... very interesting. I'll see if it makes a difference if I define the activations table also... is the only thing I can see that might cause the issue... Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just print out the error message to see what's causing the error? print `$mysqli->error`.

Answer (score 2):

It would return `false` if the execution had failed and any error had been raised. Returning `true` means query was successfully executed.

Use `$result->num_rows` to find number of rows that query resulted.

Comment: $results->num_rows on the first query throws an error saying the object doesn't exist. On the second query it reports 0 rows.

Comment: I know this doesn't make a difference but just to elaborate a little, I run this script directly after I create the entire database and the tables. As such, both tables exist and both tables are guaranteed to be empty at this point.